# javascript stop onclick function propagation

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, django

I am developing an application in django, but I have a problem with JAVASCRIPT.
By the way I am new in web development, I am beginninng to learn python an javascript.

I have an html table rendered from django and I insert a drop down button in the first column of the table with this function

```
function GetAllValues() {
var tbl = document.getElementById("myTable");
for (var i = 1; i < tbl.rows.length; i++){
           tbl.rows[i].cells[3].innerHTML = '<div class="btn-group">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">'
                                + tbl.rows[i].cells[3].innerHTML +
                            '<span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a id="configura" onclick="configp();" >Configura</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a id="recepcion" onclick="param(); return false;">Recepcion de Archivos</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a id="carga" onclick="cargaf(); return false;">Carga de Archivos</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a id="conci" onclick="concif(); return false;">Detalle Conciliacion</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>'

 }
```

Every button call a different function to redirect to another page with some forms.
I use function like this to redirect to the forms:

```
function configp(event){
  var tbl = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var rows = tbl.rows;
  var argu = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
   rows[i].onclick =  function(){
   idpro = this.cells;
   argu = "?idprov="+idpro[0].innerHTML;
   window.location = "/config/"+argu;
   }
  }
}
```

the function take some values of the table and pass it as argument to the url.
(why I am redirecting like this. Long history)

My problem is the onclick propagation.

I try putting return false before the last "}" in the configp() function and doesn't work.
I try to stop the propagation using event.preventdefault() and e.stopPropagation() any of those method can stop the propagation.

How can I stop the onclick propagation in the dropdown button

Any advice

THANKS IN ADVANCE

**UPDATE**
In simple words: when I click in the first option of the dropdown the function redirect me to the page that i want. if get back to the original page, no matters what option I clicked always redirect to the page where I was redirected to the page assigned to the first option. and the onclick event bubble in all the levels of the dropdown

Comment: This is a lot to read and piece back together. Do you have this available online anywhere?

Comment: @Alfredo It not online because the application use django (python) and I dont have a web server where to host the app abd make it public. Is for the local use the application

Comment: @joseleg You can post a stripped-down version on http://jsfiddle.net